# Customize the HTML of a link field from a custom theme

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I've a *Link* field named `field_home_link`, attached to a *Content Type* named `Home`, and I'm trying to customize how it is rendered as HTML from inside a custom theme.

Instead of the default generated HTML:

```
<a tabindex="0" href="http://example.com">Link text</a>
```

I need to render this HTML, adding custom CSS classes on it:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="btn-circle btn-circle--blue js-open-modal">
  Link text
</a>
```

But I would like to have **most flexibility as possible** on the rendered HTML, not only adding classes. For example I might need to add other attributes on the tag `<a>` or maybe also change the tag `<a>` with something else.

Would be enough having access to the link's properties (url and text) and arrange them in some custom HTML code.

How can I do this?

---

I tried to create a template for the link field:

```
field--field-home-link.html.twig
```

but inside this template I don't know how to access link's elements (url and text) and I'm stuck with this:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <!-- item.content contains the link element -->
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there no way to do something like this?:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <a href="{{ item.content.url }}" class="btn-circle btn-circle--blue js-open-modal">
    {{ item.content.text }}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <a href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}" class="btn-circle btn-circle--blue js-open-modal">
    {{ item.content.text }}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Found it in a video from 2015, where MortenDK is showing off
It's about 25 min. in

[DrupalCon Los Angeles 2015: Drupal 8 Theming with Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvaz9eb54c4)

Comment: `{{ item.content.text }}` should be `{{ item.content['#title'] }}`

Answer (score 3):

Spent 2 days on this similar problem. Sebastian, you almost had it. Twig snippet should look more like this:

```
{% for item in items %}  
  <a href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}" class="btn-circle btn-circle--blue js-open-modal">
    {{ item.content.['#title'] }}  
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

`['#title']` - is really important to place the text in the a href tag

Definitely MortenDK was very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvaz9eb54c4

Comment: I suggested a change to Sebastian's answer, hopefully it would just get accepted and we'd reduce these duplicate options and help others save time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using views (as I understood as you mentioned the machine name `field_home_link`, you can simply hide the link field by ticking the checkbox saying *Exclude from display* in view.

Below you will see replacement patterns and overwrite option where you can write your snippet-

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="btn-circle btn-circle--blue js-open-modal">
  Link text
</a>
```

save your view, it's done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not using views.. I created a *Content Type* and just added a new field of type *Link* with internal name `field_home_link`.

Comment: Sorry, do you use display suite (drupal/projects/ds)?

Comment: No, I don't use Display Suite.. Do you think it can be useful for my question?

Comment: Can you install link module, go to field settings of your field and update me whether you see a custom classes option?

Comment: DS helps with classes and manage how to display your fields with custom classes.

Comment: Mmmm.. Is there no way to manage how fields are displayed from template files directly? It would be more "normal".. I would avoid setting classes from the admin panel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38810/discussion-between-rees-and-andrea).

Answer (score 1):

I have tested for both external and internal URL by using like below, it's working as desired.

```
<a href="{{ content.field_my_link[0]['#url'] }}" class="button buy-now-btn">{{ content.field_my_link[0]['#title'] }}</a>
```